# Best practice / design pattern for a vcard/mecard parser?

Tags: parsing, design-patterns, vcf-vcard

I have implemented a VCARD parser in objective c. Now I want to add support for the MECARD standard. The only difference of a VCARD and a MECARD are the different separators between the fields. Now I'm looking for a good design pattern that helps me to combine both standards into one parser.

Are there any best practices or design patterns for such text parsers?

Comment: Do you need anything else but a single parameter?

Comment: @Ondrej: Thanks for your reply. Yes, there are some slight differences between vcards an mecards

Comment: Hi Pino - I have the same challenge.  Did you ever write one?

Comment: Your question contains a mistake. There are some differences between them: https://www.devicemedia.ca/blog/whats-the-difference-between-a-vcard-and-a-mecard/

Answer (score 0):

If your main difference is the separator, abstract it out by creating a parse function that takes your raw input and converts it into an array or some other data structure that does not need separators.